# How to publish my visual studio 2013 C# .NET MVC Website to Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have created a project using C#.NET MVC 4.0 and I want to publish the project (website) to my azure account... I cannot see any way of publishing my project to my windows azure? I have followed the Cloud service set up guide only to be utterly confused at how I link it up to my existing project?

Any help?

So overview is, I have a project (MVC web application) and I just want to publish it to azure so that it works like a website others can view.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this really, but I would guess you right click the project in project explorer and go to `publish` or `deploy`. Just a guess

Comment: ARGHH I HAD NO IDEA THAT WAS THERE... DOh doh. thankyou lmao... dude put that as the answer man!

Comment: Lol my friend just made fun of me for being such a noob... In all fairness, I am insanely handsome... I can't be both intelligent and handsome... right?

Comment: Life is tough for the good looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try right clicking the project in the `Project Explorer` section and look for something along the lines of `Publish` or `Deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways of getting your MVC project "out there" is to go to the Azure portal, and create a new "Web Site". The difference between Azure Websites and Azure Cloud Services are answered in other questions here on Stack. Here is how you can do it with Azure Websites:

1. In the Azure portal create a new website.
2. On the WebSites dashboard, click the link "Download the publish profile".
3. Open up your solution in Visual Studio 2013, right click your web-project and select "Publish...".
4. In the dialogbox, click "Import..." to import the publish profile you just downloaded.
5. Hit the "Validate Connection" button to verify that everything is OK.
6. Click publish and your MVC application gets published to your newly created Azure Website.

Another option is to deploy directly from sourcecontrol eg. GitHub. Follow the wizard in the Azure portal. In the website dashboard, hit the link "Set up deployment from source control".

Answer (score 0):

yes goto azure portal - create website and keep it in start mode
come to visual studio select publish -- Import from azure website - just enter your credentials and automatically VS gets the settings and displays the website that we created - just select from the list..that's it - this is without explicitly downloading the publish profile.